# Encryption and decryption in windows based and UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Need to save password in encrypted format in xml file from Windows application(.net framework 4.6). used ICryptoTransform to encrypt the password.

Reading data from local file and need to decry-pt the pasword saved in xml file from Universal windows class library. but ICryptoTransform was not supported in the Windows.Security.

Comment: Although `ICryptoTransform`  was not supported in UWP directly. But it could works in .NET Standard. So you could create .NET Standard class library and refer it in UWP project.  And use NET Standard class library to encryption and decryption, process Plaintext in uwp project.

Comment: Hi there, see if my solution would work for you.  I wanted to protect my users' API keys.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819635/i-want-to-protect-the-users-api-public-and-secret-keys-in-my-uwp-app